# Prove that the union of increasing $\sigma$-field is not a $\sigma$-field

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Find examples where $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2 \subseteq \cdots$ are increasing $\sigma$-fields but $\bigcup_{n = 1} ^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$ is not. I have constructed an example that I believe is correct, but having trouble to show this is actually the right counter-example:

Define $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{ [0, i]: i \leq n \})$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then I believe $\bigcup_{i = 1} ^\infty [0, i] = [0, \infty) \not\in \bigcup_{n = 1} ^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$.

However, I am having trouble to show $[0, \infty) \not\in \bigcup_{n= 1} ^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$. Any suggestions?

Comment: My earlier comment was based on the wrong assumption that your universal set was $[0,\infty)$, instead of $\mathbb R$. I have deleted the comment and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\{1\},\{2\},..,\{n-1\}, [0,1],(1,2], (2,3],...,(n-1,n],\mathbb R \setminus [0,n]$ is a partition of the real line, and it is easy to check that $\mathcal F_n$ is also the $\sigma-$ algebra generated by this partition. This implies that every set in $\mathcal F_n$ is a union of of some sets from this collection. If $[0,\infty)$ belongs to $\mathcal F_n$ it follows that $[0,\infty)$ must be a union of sets on which is necessarily $\mathbb R \setminus [0,n]$ (since $[0,\infty)$ is unbounded). But then  $(-\infty,0)\subseteq \mathbb R \setminus [0,n] \subseteq [0,\infty)$ which is a contradiction.

Remark: The $\sigma-$ algebra generated by any countable partition $A_1,A_2,...$ is the collection of all possible unions of the sets $A_i$.